# Почему у меня нет Android Profiler (Android Studio 3.5)

Tags: android-studio

Почему у меня нет Android Profiler (монитор ресурсов) как его поставить или где его найти ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

**View > Tool Windows > Profiler**

> Если вы подключили устройство через USB, но не видите его в списке,
>   убедитесь, что вы включили отладку по USB .

[ссылка](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)